# Copying a Laravel's .env file into a Docker container

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, docker

Setup

I'm running Docker on my Ubuntu server and I'm trying create a Laravel container to run my website with artisan. The Laravel project is inside a GitHub Repository and I clone the project to the docker container with a dockerfile.

Problem

Laravel projects are dependent on the `.env` (environment files) which are not included in the repo project, for security reasons. So when I clone the repo to the docker container it doesn't include the .env file and thereby doesn't run the website properly. I have an `.env` file locally on my Ubuntu that I'm trying to `COPY` to the docker container Laravel project folder, ofcourse it doesn't work. This is because it's looking for the directory in the docker container's file structure.

Error

```
Step 6/11 : COPY /containers/.env .env

lstat containers/.env: no such file or directory
```

Question

How can I copy the .env file from the ubuntu server to the docker container with the `COPY` command?

file structure (Ubuntu) source from:

```
root/
  containers/
    - docker-compose
    - .env
```

file structure (docker container) source to:

```
root/
  var/www/
```

dockerfile

```
FROM hitalos/laravel

RUN git config --system http.sslverify false

RUN git clone repo /var/www

RUN git checkout test

COPY /containers/.env .env

# Run Compser Install
RUN composer install -d /var/www
RUN php /var/www/artisan key:generate

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD php /var/www/artisan serve --port=80 --host=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: why don't you checkout the repo in the host machine, it is not necessary to have the repo in the image/container, you can copy it as well

Answer (score 9):

Simply copying the .env file is not going to work since you also have to run a `source` command on the file and then an `export` command to add each environment variable to your path.

Since you are using docker-compose then you can use the env_file like so in your docker-compose.yml:

`env_file:
    -.env`

This should automatically set the values required by Laravel from your .env file when you build your conainer.

Comment: Yup, I also think that COPY an .env file is not right, and feels dirty! But that if you need those variables at build stage specifically, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459243/docker-compose-build-time-args-from-file (sorry for the piggy back on an old question) :D

Answer (score 2):

The path in `COPY` is relative to the `Dockerfile`

just change it to `COPY containers/.env /var/www/.env`

EDIT:
seems like you don't have the `.env` file at build time (image), only at runtime (container). That means, you have to mount the file when running the container.

Remove the `COPY ...` command from Dockerfile and instead run the container with

`-v /containers/.env:/var/www/.env`

so something like this:

`docker run... -v /containers/.env:/var/www/.env ...`

or change it in the compose yml file

Comment: Didn't work still getting: lstat containers/.env: no such file or directory

Comment: I think I need to remotly access the Ubuntu server somehow to get access ti the directory containers.

Comment: Wait. You are building the images locally, but running the container on the ubuntu server where you have no access?

Comment: If you need the .env file at runtime (container), but you don't have the file at build time (image), then simply build it without any COPY command and just simply mount the volume to the container at runtime (`docker run... -v /containers/.env:/var/www/.env ... `

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -d --network=your-network --restart unless-stopped --name your-container-name --env-file /host/path/to/.env your-container/name
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.